# How to line break text inside modal's buttons

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, overflow

I'm using antd and ReactJS to create a modal with customized buttons. These buttons' text could be changeable from the user.

What I noticed that on providing a very large text but as one-word it will always over flow button size/modal size and make things looks bad. Even tho it might be a very corner case for a user to set a button's text to be that long, I want to know how to handle it.

I made a little search and tried some solutions from [How to Create Button with Line Breaks](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/button-with-line-breaks.html#:%7E:text=Another%20way%20of%20adding%20a,property%20and%20set%20the%20width.)

but this what I get when I try to break it
[image: Broken button text]

On the other hand it should be something like that [image]

This is the code I'm using for the modal.

```
         <Modal
            title={'Consent'}
            closable={false}
            width='100vw'
            visible={visible}
            onCancel={onDisagree}
            footer={[
                <Fragment key="consentButtons">
                    <Popconfirm
                        placement="topRight"
                        title="Do you want to continue?"
                        onConfirm={onDisagree}
                        okText="Yes"
                        cancelText="No"
                    >
                        <Button type='ghost' key="disagree"> {disagree} </Button>
                    </Popconfirm>
                    <Button type='primary' key="agree" onClick={onAgree}>{agree}</Button>
                </Fragment>
            ]}>
            <RichText value={content}/>
        </Modal>
```

---

I managed to solve my issue using :

```
wordBreak: 'break-all',
whiteSpace: 'normal'
```

and for dynamic height for multiline text that will be broken I used `height: 'fit-content'`

Comment: Can you add your css? I think by adding word-wrap: break-word; in your button should work.

Comment: @Eriksen I'm not using any css, as I'm using antd which already got it's own styls, but I tried word-wrap: break-word; and it stayed the same

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass custom css then it may help you.

```css
.myButtonWrap {
    postion:absolute;
    border:1px solid;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    block:inline;
    width:200px;
    background-color: #000;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-decoration:none;
    
}
```

```html
<button  class="myButtonWrap" style="background-color:white;color:#000;">qwertqwertyqwertystackoverflowstackoverflowwrapthebuttonwrapthebuttonokokokokokokoqwertyuiopertyuiodshfgdsfhdsfhdofhdsofhdsofdosfhdsfhsdofhdofhodufhdufdufgdusiosdifhdsiloremcdschdgcdkcgsdkcggo;faofefefwe</button>
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Can button width be something more to dynamic according to text width?

Comment: I appreciate ur help, I managed to apply it using word-break, and white-space

Comment: Okay no problem.